# Interface Inheritance and Sub-Interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

interface IA : interface IB
{ ... }

So IB is the parent interface of IA, IA is the _____ of IB. What should be put in the blank? sub-interface?

Comment: If you are going to post homework, at least tag it as such, give more context and try to indicate at what point you got stuck while trying to answer it yourself.

Comment: It is not a homework... just do not know how to describe that.
For class I can say A is sub-class of B, but I am not sure if the saying sub-interface is correct

Comment: I think "descendant" is what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no inheritance relationship between .NET interfaces. This is evident if you use Reflection - `typeof(IB).BaseType` will be `null`, not `IB`.

Personally, I prefer to think of interfaces as contracts. In this case, "inheritance" of interfaces is really just strengthening the contract - so I'd say "contract `IB` implies `IA`". Eric Lippert [seems to share](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=28) this point of view:

> He regards extension as being about reuse of implementation, whereas specifying a "base" interface is about saying that "any object fulfilling this contract must also fulfill this other interface".

Alternatively, "`IA` extends `IB`" sounds understandable while being technically correct (if we're talking about extending a contract), though perhaps somewhat misleading, as we're tightening the contract in "extended" interface, not relaxing it.

Yet another way is to go with what C# language specification uses. That one has a section on the topic titled "Base interfaces", and starts with the following sentence:

> An interface can **inherit** from zero or more interface types, which are called the explicit **base interfaces** of the interface.

So there you have it. Though it should be noted that this is for C# 3.0; past versions of the spec actually used "extends" rather than "inherits" to describe the same thing, so there is still some possibility of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that IA is the **subinterface** of IB, and IA **extends** IB.

So, IB is the **superinterface** of IA.

All classes based on these interfaces **implements** them.